# How can i use multiprocessing in class

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm making program for study python.
it is gui web crawler.
i success multi work gui and main classes using QThread
but i have a problem.
in main class, get picture addresses using webdriver first, and make a list called data.
after that use pool() and map() to start download pictures using download_image method in Main class.

i searched and tried many things.
imap and lambda etc.

here is my code
(i import multiprocess as mul)
(and my python version is 3.7)

```
# crawler and downloader class
class Main(QThread, QObject):
    def __init__(self, path, brand, model, grade):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.path = path

    # this is download method
    def download_image(self, var):
        a = var.split("/")
        filename = a[-1]
        download_path = self.path + filename
        urllib.request.urlretreieve(var, download_path)

    # this is start method when button clicked in Gui
    def core(self):
        #sample url data list
        data = ['url.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com', ...]
        download_p = Pool(mul.cpu_count())
        download_p.map(self.download_image, data)
        download_p.close()
        download_p.join()
        print("end")

    def run(self):
        self.core()


class Gui(QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        (and gui code here)
```

if i set download_p.map(self.download_image, data)
i get this error -> [ TypeError: can't pickle Main objects ]

if i set download_p.map(self.download_image, self.data)
(and also set self.data = [urls...])
i get same TypeError

if i set download_p.map(self.download_image, self, data)
i get this error -> [TypeError : 'Main' object is not iterable

I'm not good at English and Python too
but i want to resolve this problem so i decide ask here
really thanks for looking this newbie's question...